# Yellowish dots and rotted stems on my palm

Tags: houseplants, palm, rot

Can anyone tell what is wrong with my palm tree. The whole centre of new growth is destroyed, the stems are mould and have collapsed and the leaves have yellowish spots.

[image]
[image]
[image]